# Procedure: Conversion Failed

Tags: sql-server

This is my procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [Ac].[SAVE]     
    @P_LIST VARCHAR(MAX) = '', 
    @P_USER_ID INT
AS
    DECLARE @ID INT;
BEGIN
    SET @ID = (NEXT VALUE FOR  Ac.SEQ)

    INSERT INTO Ac.Parameter (ID, NAME, VALUE, MODIFIED_BY, MODIFIED_ON)
    VALUES (@ID, 'LIST', @P_LIST, @P_USER_ID, GETDATE())

    SELECT @ID AS ID;       
END
```

While executing this procedure with value like this:

```
   exec [Ac].[SAVE] @P_LIST ='6854,6891', @P_USER_ID  = 2965
```

I am getting this error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '6854,6891' to data type int.

But when I execute it like below, there is no issue:

```
exec [Ac].[SAVE] @P_LIST ='6854', @P_USER_ID  = 2965
```

If I simply execute insert query without using procedure like this:

```
INSERT INTO Ac.Parameter(ID, NAME, VALUE, MODIFIED_BY, MODIFIED_ON)
VALUES (1, 'LIST', '6854,6891', 2965, GETDATE())
```

it's also fine and inserts successfully.

Column datatypes:

- ID int
- NAME varchar(64)
- VALUE varchar(8000)
- MODIFIED_BY int
- MODIFIED_ON datetime

Comment: You try to insert the string '6854,6891' into an int column. I suppose you are missing the splitting of the string into separate values. Or is '6854,6891' supposed to be a decimal number? In this case replace ',' with '.'

Answer (score 0):

The value column in the `Ac.Parameter` table appears to be an int - you are trying to insert a string which is not convertable to an int. Your procedure as is will obviously only work if the value is convertable to one, as your example shows (SQL Server is converting the string for you when it can).

Presumably what you actually want to do is convert the whole proc to work with multiple values - there's no magic bullet which will make it work now, you haven't written most of your procedure to handle multiple values.

Assuming you re-write your business logic to handle multiple values, you'd either need to:

- Create a table type parameter, populate it, and pass that to the stored proc (assumes SQL Server 2008+ - this is the best option)
- Split the parameter string into a table of separate integer values
- Other methods - shared processing table, pass string as XML instead etc. - see http://sommarskog.se/share_data.html for a pros and cons of each

Answer (score 0):

You should split up the string into separate values and then use these for further processing. The following example fills the variable @t with the single int values. If you use this within your procedure, you can loop over all results and insert them as required.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(tVal int);

DECLARE @P_LIST VARCHAR(MAX)='6854,6891'

IF CHARINDEX(',', @P_LIST) = 0
  INSERT INTO @t VALUES (CONVERT(int, @P_LIST));
ELSE
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @start INT, @end INT 
    SELECT @start = 1, @end = CHARINDEX(',', @P_LIST) 
    WHILE @start < LEN(@P_LIST) + 1 BEGIN 
        IF @end = 0  
            SET @end = LEN(@P_LIST) + 1

        INSERT INTO @t
        VALUES(SUBSTRING(@P_LIST, @start, @end - @start)) 
        SET @start = @end + 1 
        SET @end = CHARINDEX(',', @P_LIST, @start)

    END 
END

SELECT *
  FROM @t
```

Answer (score -1):

Column Value in Ac.Parameter must be integer column. You are trying to insert '6854,6891' there. It causes an error. And '6854' is integer that's why it works. If You want to have Int conversion made before insert, use :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [Ac].[SAVE]     
@P_LIST VARCHAR(MAX)=''     
AS
DECLARE @ID INT;
BEGIN
SET @ID = (NEXT VALUE FOR  Ac.SEQ)

INSERT INTO Ac.Parameter
    (ID, NAME, VALUE, MODIFIED_BY, MODIFIED_ON)
VALUES                      
    (@ID, 'LIST', CONVERT(INT, @P_LIST), @P_USER_ID, GETDATE()),          

SELECT @ID AS ID;       
END
```

Comment: @LimnaD'silva please double check it. If it is trully varchar(8000). Also maybe there is trigger on this table that is doing something with this value?

Comment: So you are trying to convert '6854,6891' into int? will it work? I haven't down voted your answer by the way.

Comment: @LimnaD'silva You want to store full '6854,6891' string there ?

Comment: why does Your Procedure have variable '@P_USER_ID' that is not declared? Maybe that's why it is trying to put wrong variable into wrong column?

Comment: It is there..Sorry, i forgot to add it in my question

Comment: Can You tell me what is '@ID' value inside procedure? Like maybe comment that insert line for time and tell me what value is selected '@ID'  when You execute?

Comment: Value of  `@ID` is taken by Sequences created in SQL server. Each time its value is incremented. Now its value is `9280`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146525/discussion-between-whencesoever-and-limna-dsilva).